# Norm of a linear map is not attained

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Prove that the norm of the linear functional

$$\phi: l^1 \ni \{x_n \} \rightarrow \sum_{n=1} ^{\infty} (1 - \frac{1}{n} )x_n \in \mathbb{K}$$

equals one but there doesn't exist a sequence $ \{x_n \} \in \mathcal{l}^1$ such that $|| \{ x_n \} || \le 1$ and $| \phi ( \{ x_n \} ) | =1$

My problem is that I don't know how to show that the norm equals one - it's easy to show that it's less or equal $1$.

I guess I need to contruct a sequence of elements of $l^1$ whose norms tend to one.

And how to prove that there doesn't exist $\{ x_n \} \in l^1$ for which the value $1$ of the norm is attained?

Could you explain that to me, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first question: Let a sequence be defined by letting $x_m=1$, and $x_k=0$ for $k \neq m$. Then what happens when $m$ goes to infinity?

For the second question:
$$
| \phi ( \{ x_n \} ) | \leq \sum_{n=1} ^{\infty} |(1 - \frac{1}{n} )x_n| < \sum_{n=1} ^{\infty} |x_n| \leq 1.
$$
The strict inequality is true for any sequence where $||\{x_n\}|| \neq 0$.

Comment: As $m \rightarrow \infty$, the sum of the series tends to one. Thank you! When it comes to the second part, the norm would only be attained if the two series in your answer were equal to $1$ but they are equal only if all the terms are $0$.

Comment: @Spencer That's correct!

Answer (score 2):

Let denote $(e_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ the canonical basis. Then $\phi (e_n)= (1-1/n)$, so for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $\| \phi \| \geq (1-1/n)$.

For your second question, observe that $|\phi (x) |\leq \sum |(1-1/n)x_n| < \sum |x_n | =1$, if $\|x \| = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Hints: To show the norm is at least $1$, try it on the "standard basis vectors" that have a single $1$ and everything else $0$.
To show there is no member of $\ell^1$ where that is attained, note that
if $x_m \ne 0$, $|\phi(x)| \le \|x\| - |x_m|/m$.